# How do I UNION over the result of a subquery without a temp table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex query which results in multiple columns which I want to UNION into a single column.

The naive UNION construct makes me place the FROM for each query to combine. I would like that FROM to be the result of the complex query.

I would like to say:

```
SELECT row1 AS result FROM (complex query)
UNION
SELECT row2 AS result FROM (same complex query)
UNION
SELECT row3 AS result FROM (same complex query)
...
```

How do I do that in MySQL 5.6.10 (I realize that CTE elegantly solves my problem), and without temp tables (my DBA is paranoid).

Comment: You can put the logic of each complex queries in separate cte and then use the cte in main query.

Comment: Your problem is not on the query but your DBA. I will pass on this.

Comment: I guess that's one reason they introduced CTE to begin with... I guess there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cte` block like below:

```
with cte as
(
   complex query comes here
)
select row1 as result from cte
union
select row2 as result from cte
...
```

Using a temptable would be another alternative solution.

For more `cte` examples: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/

EDIT: Since OP is using an older version, this is an alternative solution:

Use a #temp table like below in your main complex query:

```
Select ...
into #temp
from ...
...
```

Then, use the #temp table for union:

```
select row1 as result from #temp
union
select row2 as result from #temp
```

Comment: CTE seems to require MySQL 8.0, I'm stuck on MySQL 5.6.10 for now.

Comment: If you can't use a CTE, you could do it the old fashioned way and put the complex query results into a temp table and then reference that in your UNION query.

Comment: @ChristianGoetze Edited my answer.

Comment: ... and I don't have permission to create temp tables, hence the subject line ...